# Error al obtener diferencia de fecha en PHP

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Estoy intentando obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas, cada una de las fechas las obtengo desde un archivo excel, estoy utilizando la libreria `Spreadsheet` y me lanza el siguiente error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string`

Este es mi código:

```
public function compruebaDif(){


    if($this->primer_arhchivo){

        $this->spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load( "Diciembre 01.xlsx");
        $this->celda_fech = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("E5")->getFormattedValue();

        $dt = new DateTime($this->celda_fech);
        $nueva = $dt->format('d/m/Y');

        $this->subFecha = $nueva;

        echo $this->subFecha;

    }elseif (!$this->primer_arhchivo){

        $this->spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load( "Diciembre 02.xlsx");
        $this->celda_fech = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("E5")->getFormattedValue();

        $dt = new DateTime($this->celda_fech);
        $nueva = $dt->format('d/m/Y');

        $this->fechActual = $nueva;

        $this->diferencia = $this->fechActual->diff($this->subFecha);

        echo $this->diferencia;
    }


    $this->primer_arhchivo = true;

}
```

Los nombres los estoy generando desde un bucle le puse Diciembre 01.xlsx para el ejemplo.

Comment: Buenas. Lo de esta variable: `$primer_arhchivo` con el arh es a propósito? o has puesto esa h por error?

Comment: Parece que `$this->subFecha`  es una cadena, no un objeto `DateTime`, no veo en ningún momento que crees una fecha a partir de ese dato. Puedes probarlo haciendo un `var_dump($this->subFecha);` y si no es `DateTime` debes crearlo antes de intentar usarlo con `diff`. También veo que mareas demasiado los datos, declarando y redeclarando cosas para los mismos usos.

Comment: `$this->fechActual` también debe ser un objeto  `DateTime`, lo puedes depurar también con un `var_dump($this->fechActual=);` y para imprimir en el `else if`  debes darle un formato también a `echo $this->diferencia;` puesto que lo que te arrojará será un objeto `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplificar el código así:

```
public function compruebaDif(){


    if($this->primer_arhchivo){

        $this->spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load( "Diciembre 01.xlsx");
        $this->celda_fech = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("E5")->getFormattedValue();
        $this->subFecha = new DateTime($this->celda_fech);
        echo $this->subFecha->format('d/m/Y');

    }elseif (!$this->primer_arhchivo){

        $this->spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load( "Diciembre 02.xlsx");
        $this->celda_fech = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("E5")->getFormattedValue();
        $this->fechActual = new DateTime($this->celda_fech);
        $this->diferencia = $this->fechActual->diff($this->subFecha);
        echo $this->diferencia->format('d/m/Y');

    }

    $this->primer_arhchivo = true;

}
```

El problema es que hay incoherencia en tu implementación, por ejemplo si analizamos esto:

```
   $dt = new DateTime($this->celda_fech);
   $nueva = $dt->format('d/m/Y');
   $this->subFecha = $nueva;
```

finalmente, lo que dejas en `$this->subFecha`  no es un objeto `DateTime`, sino una cadena con la fecha representada en el formado `d/m/Y`. Si estás en una clase y quieres hacer operaciones de fechas como `diff`, los miembros de la clase que uses deben ser objetos `DateTime`, si son cadenas u otros tipos de objetos, dará el error que estás teniendo precisamente: *`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string`*

Por ejemplo aquí:

```
    $this->diferencia = $this->fechActual->diff($this->subFecha);
```

Tanto `$this->fechActual` como `$this->subFecha` deben ser objetos `DateTime`. Si en alguna parte has invocado un método que ha dado a los miembros `subFecha` o `fechaActual` un valor como lo que haces más arriba: `$this->subFecha = $nueva;` vas a tener ese problema.

También he corregido lo de la salida, puedes imprimir a partir del mismo objeto, dándole formato y sin perder el objeto, por ejemplo: `echo $this->subFecha->format('d/m/Y');`

También he reducido variables que creabas de forma innecesaria.

Si manejas los miembros de la clase de una forma coherente no deberías tener problemas.

Comment: Gracias maestro, tienes razon!
Un saludo!